# Python one-liner to map array to string format

Tags: python, arrays, list

Similar to javascript, how could I map a list to a string format in Python?

Such as

```
final_str = mylist.map(n => f'{n.id} {n.name}\n')
```

And the resulting string would be

```
id1 name1
id2 name2
...etc
```

Comment: What type of "array" do you have?  This is not a Python built-in, but NumPy and Array packages include that type.  Alternately, do you want to operate on a list or tuple?  What part of the conversion is giving you problems?  Please post your attempt so far.

Comment: Give a sample `mylist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join()` with a generator expression:

```
final_str = '\n'.join(f"{item.id} {item.name}" for item in mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

First define a class that has `id` and `name` attributes.  And include a `__str__` method (and `__repr__` would be nice):

```
In [257]: class Foo(): 
     ...:     def __init__(self,id,name): 
     ...:         self.id=id 
     ...:         self.name=name 
     ...:     def __str__(self): 
     ...:         return f'{self.id} {self.name}' 
     ...:
```

Create an example:

```
In [258]: Foo('id1','name1')                                                                         
Out[258]: <__main__.Foo at 0x7fa6531c5160>
In [259]: print(_)                                                                                   
id1 name1
```

Then making a list of the strings (the class is doing the heavy lifting):

```
In [260]: [str(n) for n in [Foo('id1','name1'), Foo('id2','name2')]]                                 
Out[260]: ['id1 name1', 'id2 name2']
```

and to make one string with \n:

```
In [261]: print('\n'.join(_))                                                                        
id1 name1
id2 name2
```

Answer (score 0):

May use list comprehension also to achieve the same:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
[str(i)+'\n' for i in l]
```